# Question about normal sub-groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

$G,H$ are groups and $H<G,H\triangleleft G$,
If $x^2\in H\; \forall x\in G$, how do I prove that $x=x^{-1}$?

I started with that $Hx^2=H$, I'm right?
If not' Id like to get a hint...

Thank you!

Comment: Think about conjugates..

Comment: @user112167 - How does it helps me? can you explain more please?

Comment: @user112167 - Can you help me with the beginning of the proof? I don't know where to start...

Comment: We have the definition that a subgroup is normal if $ghg^{-1} \in H$ for all $h \in H$ and $g \in G$. Now what does $x^2 \in H$, for all $x \in G$ tells us?

Comment: I try this way but I didn't succeed! it tells that $x^{-1}\cdot x^2 \cdot x\in H$....

Comment: @user112167 - $x\cdot x^2 \cdot x^{-1}=x^2$?????

Comment: @user112167 - did you saw my proof at the answers?

Comment: I think you may have wanted to prove that $\;x^2\in H\iff xH=x^{-1}H\;,\;\forall\,x\in G\;$ . This is true.

Answer (score 2):

This seems false, for $G=S_n,$ $H=A_n.$

Comment: So, let say that we talking about finite groups

Comment: Those groups *are* finite...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something, tell if I'm right....
If for $\forall x\in G,\,x^2\in H$ so: $$Hx^2=H\,\Rightarrow Hx^2=He\Rightarrow Hx\cdot x=He\\\Rightarrow (Hx)(Hx)=He\Rightarrow e=x\cdot x\Rightarrow x=x^{-1} $$
I'm right?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm right? I'll be gald if you will correct my...Thank you!

Comment: No, it's not right. Sorry. The only thing you can deduce so far is $\; x^2\in H\iff x^2H=H\iff G/H\;$ is $\;2$ - elementary group (and thus abelian, of course).

Comment: What do you mean at "$G/H$ is $2$" thank you!

Comment: Read the whole thing, Yoav: "...is a 2 - elementary group"